# Why I can't change the Button's textColor

Tags: android, button

I try to change the button textColor's parameter, but all my efforts below are in vain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="fragment_register">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_first_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#3f3f3f"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:ems="17"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enter_password"
        android:textColorHint="#696969"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_first_pass_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#3f3f3f"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:ems="17"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:hint="@string/hint_reenter_password"
        android:textColorHint="#696969"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#494949"
        android:text="@string/btn_title_reg"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The color has changed only in Preview Design Layout window, but it doesn't work in launched app. 
`button.setTextColor(...);`    It doesn't work as well

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You are using tools:textColor and not android:textColor

Comment: android:textColor="@android:color/white"   doesn't work as well

Comment: Try to show all of your code, maybe it is being changed somewhere else. The above code should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

`android:textColor="#FFFFFF"`

instead of

`tools:textColor="@android:color/white"`

or try to set programatically like this

```
button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this,R.color.colorBlack));
```

Comment: but why it works in Preview Design Layout Window? I can't understand

Comment: @MisterSmith show all of your code, maybe it is being changed somewhere else

Comment: @MisterSmith try to set programatically

Answer (score 0):

Try clear your project before building it

```
Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Sometimes android catch some of the previous build to save build time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000fff"));
```

or you can use

```
button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```